Can I use the first derivative to solve for points of inflection in the logistic model?
I am very new to calculus and am completing an assignment on the logistic model. My friend and I watched a video that explained that the local maximum/minimum point of the first derivative of the logistic function is the x coordinate of the point of inflection. Is this true?
Because I have since read information that says we have to find the point where the second derivative equals zero. My friend thinks that the local maximum of the first derivative is the same x coordinate as when the second derivative equals zero but I dont know if this is true.
It doesnt need to be the most theoretically accurate answer, I just need to know if it works in a practical sense because I have found all the points of inflection in my assessment like this and im praying I dont have to re write the whole thing.
Thank you so much for your help and I'm sorry my wording isnt very clear

If $x = c$ is a local max (or min) of $f'(x)$ then certainly $f''(c) = 0.$ You still have to take the second derivative anyway.

If you think about he logistic curve  geometrically you will be able to answer your question about  the inflection point - it's where the population growth rate switches from increasing to decreasing (the population itself keeps increasing).  That's a statement about the first derivative. You can translate that into a statement about the second derivative if you wish.

(Picture from wikipedia's logistic function page.)
